# Android 4.1 Webview.loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders) not working with 2 or multiple headers

Tags: android, webview

This is my code:

```
String urlBase = "http://" + host + "/rashome/";

String paramsClear = "login" + ":" + "true" + ":" + email + ":" + password + ":" + lang + ":" + isFastConn;

String paramsBase64Encode = Base64.encodeToString(paramsClear.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

paramsMap.put("credentials", paramsBase64Encode);
paramsMap.put("imei", imei);
if(!token.equals("")) {
    paramsMap.put("token", token);
} 
webview.loadUrl(urlBase, paramsMap);
```

That is working fine on Webview Android 4.4+ (server receive all parameters), but on Webview Android 4.1 or under 4.4, it can't send imei and token value to server. I am too confused about this.

Comment: Are you getting any error message

Comment: No, no error message. But my server just receive credentials and return empty imei and token value.

Comment: Is it only IMEI and token parameters ? (credentials is ok) How do you get imei value ?